# How to set specific type of location on google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to get nearby location of specific type but that type is not exist on google map. I want to add that type. Is it possible that we can add types on google map.

Answer (score 0):

> types are not exist on google map.

You can add this code:

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
                service.nearbySearch({
                    location: theLocation.value,
                    radius: radius,
                    type: ['restaurant'], 
                    openNow: true,
                    minPriceLevel: minprice

                }, yourCallback);
```

And specify the type of location that you want to find with the `type` parameter (here we find some restaurants).

You may consult the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) the type parameter is specified in the description of nearby search.

*Tell me if you have some questions.*

Comment: I m Developing app for tailors. I need to search nearby tailors only. but there is no type for tailors. I will store tailors and there location on my database.

Comment: Ok, it is not my speciality but you can consult [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps) page on google.

Answer (score 0):

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
                service.nearbySearch({
                    location: theLocation.value,
                    radius: radius,
                    type: ['restaurant'], 
                    openNow: true,
                    minPriceLevel: minprice

                }, yourCallback);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).